# SQL counts when using group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with three columns (ItemNo, Size, StockBalance) that looks like:

A1, XS, 2
A1, S, 0
A1, M, 3
A1, L, 3
A1, XL, 0
A2, XS, 5
A2, S, 0
A2, M, 1
A2, L, 3
A2, XL, 6

If I run

SELECT ItemNo, sum(StockBalance), COUNT(*) FROM StockTable GROUP BY ItemNo

I get

A1, 8, 5
A2, 15, 5

Which is great, as I know how many unique items I have, the total stock position for each item and the number of sizes for each item.

What I also want is the number of sizes in stock i.e. for A1 it would be 3 and for A2 it would be 4.

I can then derive a final column which is the percentage of sizes in stock i.e. for A1 it would be 3/5 = 0.6 and for A2 it would be 4/5 = 0.8

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
SELECT ItemNo, sum(StockBalance) Total, COUNT(*) Sizes,
COUNT(CASE WHEN StockBalance>0 THEN 1 END) SIZESinSTOCK 
FROM StockTable GROUP BY ItemNo
```

This will consider only records with a StockBalance>0.

To also get your last column you could do

```
SELECT *, 1.*SIZESinSTOCK/Sizes InStockPercent FROM (
  SELECT ItemNo, sum(StockBalance) Total, COUNT(*) Sizes,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN StockBalance>0 THEN 1 END) SIZESinSTOCK 
  FROM StockTable GROUP BY ItemNo) tmp
```

The `1.*` is needed to convert `SIZESinSTOCK`  into a floating number. Otherwise you would only get 0 or 1 as results.

Comment: CORRECT! Reason it wasn't working is I had: COUNT(CASE WHEN StockBalance>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

Comment: Well, you can still get your version to work if you use `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()`.

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do

```
SELECT 
    ItemNo, SUM(StockBalance) AS Balance, COUNT(*) as Count, SUM(IF(StockBalance > 0, 1, 0)) AS Size 
FROM StockTable 
GROUP BY ItemNo
```